# Unable to successfully finish creating a bug in TFS through the API

Tags: api, jmeter, tfs-2015

All below steps are taken with **Jmeter** tool

**TFS version 2015.**

My settings are below:

Server Name: `tfs2015.mycompany.com`

Port Number: `8080`

Path: `/tfs/SomePath/AnotherPath/_apis/wit/workitems/$Bug?api-version=2.0`

Method: `PATCH`

Body Data:

```
[
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.Title",
    "value": "My Beautiful Title"
  }, 
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.AssignedTo",
    "value": "John Doe"
  },
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.IterationPath",
    "value": "MyProject\\Iteration 10"
  },
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Severity",
    "value": "2 - High"
  },
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.ReproSteps",
    "value": "First of all do that, then do this"
  }
]
```

When calling this API I'm getting:

```
{"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"You must pass a valid patch document in the body of the request.","typeName":"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssPropertyValidationException, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=token","typeKey":"VssPropertyValidationException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}
```

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/work-items/guidance/work-item-field?view=tfs-2015 I followed all the right steps to build the body of the request:

[image: AssignedTo]

---

[image: Title]

---

[image: IterationPath]

---

[image: Severity]

---

[image: ReproSteps]

---

I simply want to create a bug and fill out necessary fields according to the below UI page

[image: TFS Web UI]

Seems like I'm following all the steps correctly, but hence can't proceed with the success. Has anyone ever experienced the same problems? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using Newtonsoft.Json 11.0.1, as there is a known issue in Newtonsoft.Json 11.0.1.

This issue has been fixed in **Newtonsoft.Json 11.0.2**, you could update Newtonsoft.Json to 11.0.2 and have another try.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but I used all aforementioned steps through Jmeter tool, and not sure how can I update Newtonsoft.Json from there

Comment: How did you reference the package?